# Is it possible to pull user information from the IDP with Azure B2C, rather than ask the user at signup?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've configured an OIDC IDP in our Azure AD B2C and wired up my app with the relevant values.

When I test the Signup and Signin user flow I'm bounced through the sign in screen for my configured IDP, but then I'm presented with a form to enter Display Name, Email address, Given Name, Job Title and Surname.

I've unchecked all User Attributes in the signup_signin User Flow but it still asks me to fill out the form.

Is it possible to skip this screen in the flow? I'd like to pull this information from the IDP once the user authenticates with the IDP, rather than ask the user to fill this out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in a user flow, but it is possible if you use custom policies.

You just remove the "SelfAsserted-Social" step.

The comment in that step says:

"These claims ensure that any values retrieved in the previous steps (e.g. from an external IDP) are prefilled. Note that some of these claims may not have any value, for example, if the external IDP did not provide any of these values, or if the claim did not appear in the OutputClaims section of the IDP."